# How does Apple Push Notifications work with HTTP/2

Tags: ios, vb.net, apple-push-notifications, http2

I have written a number of enterprise iOS apps for our company, all of which have been using the Apple Push Notification function.

I've also written the server-side code for sending the notifications without using a third-party API. It all works great.

Now, Apple is deprecating the old method for sending notifications and moving to an HTTP/2-based system.

I am trying to understand how the HTTP/2 protocol fits in with server-side code in issuing push notifications.

Isn't HTTP/2 just a standard for browsers to follow?

I've studied as much as I can of the Apple documentation for this, and it's no more clear to me now than it was before.

Please pardon my ignorance on this, but even getting the old system to work was an enormous accomplishment for me.

I wish I didn't have to change it.

Comment: The new system just uses HTTP transport rather than a raw socket transport. The fact that it supports HTTP/2 shouldn't matter.  HTTP/2 provides benefits with multiple, short connections as you get with sending push notifications.  I would suspect that your server side development language would have in-built support for sending HTTP requests and there is a good chance that that framework will handle HTTP/2; even if it doensn't HTTP client code will still work.

Comment: Depending on the technology your server uses (node.is, .net, php etc) there is probably a apns module already available that you can use

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you. I am using .net. Can you tell me where to find the proper APNs module?

Comment: Just search in google. I haven't used any particular one. Here is one https://github.com/alexalok/dotAPNS for example.

Comment: @Paulw11 It occurred to me after I posted that that I should do it myself. Sorry for putting it on you. Thanks again for your help.